# How Texture Prefetch works?

Tags: opengl, texture, gpu, optimisation

I know GPU prefetches textures and that's why dependent texture reads are slower, but how does it work and at what point that happens?

---

EDIT: Split the content of this question into others as suggested by trichoplax
Here's a link to other questions:

[How does Texture Cache work considering multiple shader units](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/355/how-does-texture-cache-work-considering-multiple-shader-units)

[How does Texture Cache work in Tile Based Rendering GPU](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/356/how-does-texture-cache-work-in-tile-based-rendering-gpu)

[Is using many texture maps bad for caching?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-using-many-texture-maps-bad-for-caching)

Comment: This seems like several interesting questions in one. At least (4), (5) and (6) sound like independent questions, and maybe (2) and (3) could be a single question. I'd upvote any of those as separate questions, but all in one it seems too broad.

Comment: Ok! Will do separates and then delete this. thx!

Comment: Actually, I just edited this and kept link to others.